# Android Places API findCurrentPlace ApiException

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have migrated my app to the new Places SDK client as per the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#find_a_place_from_the_users_location)

The findCurrentPlace request now fails with: `W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhere else in the code which called `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory()` and `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultlHostnameVerifier`. Changing these obviously affects the Places SDK's ssl connection.

Fix: change the connection SSLSocketFactory of the HttpsURLConnection instance rather than the default.